# Using Java libraries to parse date in particular form

Tags: java, date

I'm running an application which gives me CSV logs as output. For the date field, it gives it to me in the following form:

"09/25/2012 08:47:46.983"

I want to read in the output data into a Java program, translating the output given and storing it as a long in my program. Does the DateFormat class or other similar class in Java allow me to specify a string in the above form? (I can write my own code to parse the above line, but I didn't want to make bad assumptions about the form of the incoming string.)

Comment: You should be able to parse it using SimpleDateFormat, except possibly the decimal portion of the seconds.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that; I wanted to keep the accuracy of the millis, but I guess I can simply add those to the end of my answer, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class TestTest {

public TestTest() {
    String dateString = "09/25/2012 08:47:46.983";

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS");

    try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

        System.out.println("Date is: " + date.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestTest test = new TestTest();
}

}
```

Comment: date.getTime() returns the long epoch value

Comment: One last question before I accept this answer. Do you know what the difference is between `"MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS"` and `"MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.mmm"`? They give different values... Or, better yet, did you get this info online? Can you give me the link?

Comment: I think the `*.mmm` version was adding extra months, as it was much bigger, but the original that you mentioned did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I checked javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

S represents milliseconds in the pattern